# Using Curl in CodeIgniter : How to send data using post method

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

Not going to succeed when trying to send data using post method. Never used it before.

This is code of executing curl:

```
$url = LICENSE_URL."validate_system_key/validate_key/";
        //url-ify the data for the POST
        $data['system_key']='A8Z0-X1N7-S1V2-Y1I5';
        $data['domain']='http://example.com';
            $fields_string = '';
            foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
            $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');


            //open connection
            $ch = curl_init();

            //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($data));
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10); # timeout after 10 seconds, you can increase it
           //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  # Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

            //execute post
            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            //close connection
            curl_close($ch);
          $result=json_decode($result,TRUE);
```

**And this is the Code On Client Url:**

```
public function validate_key(){
        $system_key=$_POST['system_key'];
        $domain=$_POST['domain'];
        $result['error']=3;
        echo json_encode($result);
}
```

**Note:** When I am not using POST method (sending data through url) evrything is fine. Its all about POST method, **not getting the mistake!** Any kind of help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: its going to be DONE when `csrf_protection=FALSE` at client URL.
Is this a right solution ? I don't think so.! Then what is the right solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `array` instead of `String` in data passed to string like below:

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value) { 
 $data[$key] = $value;
}
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: its going to be DONE when `csrf_protection=FALSE` at client URL.
Is this a right solution ? I don't think so.! Then what is the right solution for this?